# In Froala 3.0.3 how do I access the global Froala object

Tags: froala

We are upgrading from Froala 2.9.5 to 3.0.3.

Currently we do this, but it does not work because jQuery is no longer used by Froala. So how do we now access the global Froala object?

```
$.FroalaEditor.RegisterCommand('insertLink', {
            title: 'Insert Link',
            focus: true,
            refreshOnCallback: false,
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure whether you are on pure javascript or on a javascript framework. I'm on Angular 2+ so I'm going to show you for that. Hopefully you can extrapolate from that.

At the top of your file

```
import FroalaEditor from 'froala-editor';
```

and where you register your command, it's now:

```
FroalaEditor.RegisterCommand('insertLink', {
        title: 'Insert Link',
        focus: true,
        refreshOnCallback: false,
        callback: ()=>{return this.InsertLinkFunction();
    });
```